# Discord.py @client.event twitter automatically post into specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py, tweepy

So i have a discord bot where its used to post a stuff from twitter timeline using tweepy, the auto post seems ok but its sending the old timeline also everytime the bot is turned on. Im still confused on how to make the bot only send new tweet from twitter timeline. Heres the code i have :

```
timeline = api.home_timeline()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for tweet in timeline:
        channel = client.get_channel(CHANNELID)
        em1 = discord.Embed(title = f'New Tweet From {tweet.user.name}.', description = f'{tweet.text}.')
        await channel.send(embed = em1)
```

Comment: well from discord.py point of view you don't have any errors or something that answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the `id`s of tweets you've already sent in a database of some sorts, and use that to filter out the ones that you *haven't* sent yet. Also I'm a bit confused why you'd do this in `on_message`? That doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Comment: Oh i see, thank you, i guess i can use json to store those "ids". Btw im planning to merge that automatic command with my other "on_message" command like "message.content", i didnt put the others here because theres a lot of it.

Comment: You can use json for that, yes. I just don't see why you'd do this in an `on_message`? Why do you only want to update the tweets once a message gets sent, and in case the server is busy, why *every time* a message gets sent? Wouldn't it be a better idea to check it automatically once every few minutes or so? (use built-in `tasks` for that).